# run command line from C# process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() hangs

Tags: c#

I am trying to run command line from my c# program. to keep it simple all i am doing is running "dir" command. then i read each line of the result. when i reach  the end of the output the program hangs. it does not do anything. Below is the program.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Cmd.exe");

        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        List<string> output = new List<string>();

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
        process.StandardInput.Flush();

        while (process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() != null)
        {

            output.Add(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());

        }
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Kill();
    }
```

Comment: If you are just trying to enumerate files in a folder, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: There's not much point in this code, you of course want to use the DirectoryInfo class.  In general, use the /c command line option to have cmd.exe execute a single command and exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cmd.exe` doesn't exit until you tell it to - you're waiting for it to complete, but it's waiting for your next command.

Try `process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");` to tell the process to quit.

Comment: Also worth noting that you don't need to call `process.Kill` *after* you've waited for the process to exit.

Comment: Also, you're consuming two lines of output every iteration but you only use one. I suggest adding the command you want executed to `startInfo.Arguments` thereby having a terminating process and not leaving the `cmd.exe` shell running and having to write `"exit"` to its standard input, then using `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)`.